# Share record behaviour

Tags: apex-sharing

On a learning perspective, how does the sharing records work when it comes to apex based sharing. For a given user and given record, can there be multiple share records of the same access level. Can there be multiple share records if they are of different access levels, if yes which one will be implemented by salesforce? Are there any factors that need to be considered while implementing apex sharing on the force.com platform? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inserting a share row results in an update of an existing share row.
>   Consider these examples: If a manual share access level is set to Read
>   and you insert a new one that’s set to Write, the original share rows
>   are updated to Write, indicating the higher level of access. If users
>   can access an account because they can access its child records
>   (contact, case, opportunity, and so on), and an account sharing rule
>   is created, the row cause of the parent implicit share is replaced by
>   the sharing rule row cause, indicating the higher level of access.